# CUDA volatile free

Tags: cuda

Could anyone please suggest me a way to free a volatile global memory variable in CUDA...

```
volatile unsigned *d_queue_L12;
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_queue_L12, CORES*MAX_12*Cache_Sets_L2*sizeof(volatile unsigned));
if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate space to L12 QUEUE vector (error code %s)!\n",     cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

err = cudaFree(d_queue_L12);
if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free L2 FLAG COUNT vector (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

gives an error:
error: argument of type "volatile unsigned int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"

Comment: What host compiler is this, and what are you hoping to achieve by using volatile in this context?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
err = cudaFree((void *)d_queue_L12);
```